# Soy Template syntax for if statement

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I have a quick question regarding Soy template syntax and parsing an object.  So I have an object I would like to conditionally print that looks like this:

```
{'paragraph':'Some important text that you want printed.'},
```

I was wondering how I could test against the first argument of 'paragraph'.  I would like to conditionally call a subtemplate based on that parameter.  For example

```
{'list':['item 1', 'item 2']}
```

I would like to try and do something like this:

```
 /**
  * Prints the text object specified.
  * @param textToPrint All of the items you want rendered on the page.
  */
 {template .printText}
    {foreach $textItem in textToPrint}
      {if $textItem[0] is 'paragraph'}          //THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION
         {call .paragraph}
            {param paragraph: $textItem[0] /}
         {/call}
      {else}
         {call .list}
            {param listItem: $textItem[0] /}
         {/call}
      {/if}
    {/foreach}
  </ul>
 {/template}
```

Does anyone know the syntax to accomplish something like this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok it should something like this I guess :

```
{if $textItem  == 'paragraph'}
```

Comment: https://github.com/liferay/soy-cheat-sheet#conditionals